# Android application cannot execute adb bugreport

Tags: android, adb

how can i excute adb, not adb shell in my app with system sign.

for example, i excute adb shell bugreport, but error message tell me should use adb bugreport.

i found many docs, but didn't solve my problem.

May I ask if there are any other options for implementing adb? We look forward to your answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you app is already on the Android device and runs with the system keys, then you don't need to use ADB. Just call `bugreport` (or `bugreportz` for the compressed version) directly as if you were running in a local shell, which is basically your running environment.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Can you share your code, which is the type that can be run in the application, thx.

Comment: @BruceYang You'll be well served by doing searches yourself in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57019096/is-it-possible-to-execute-shell-scripts-from-android-application